# generate XSD type xs according to XML element data

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd.exe

I have following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Test>
  <TestNumber>1</TestNumber>
  <TestName>Hello World</TestName>
</Test>
```

When generated **xsd** using xsd.exe, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="Test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="TestNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="TestName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="Test" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there a possibility that `xs:element type` of name=`TestNumber` automatically detect type of value and assign type `xs:integer`to it?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the capabilities of the `xsd.exe` tool you used?  If so, you should clarify and add that tag.

Comment: Is there a even a capability in xsd.exe tool? I want to know, adding tag.